UKVI refusal received on 06/06/2024
I am asking a question here regarding my UK visit visa refusal which I received on 06/06/2024.
I am a Pakistani national employed in a local tourism company registered with local chamber of Commerce and industry and also recognised by revenue board of Pakistan.
In refusal letter ECO cited that as I am employed at the above company, it was reasonable for you to provide the online authentication of the company and he further said that checks were being carried out and we don't find it online.
Moreover, he said that the email you provided is not your email as I provided noc from employer on company letterhead they told that it is my email but actually it was letterhead of the company so they mixed it up.
They acknowledged my monthly salaries credited into my account. They said that company was not corrborated but this was wrong as my boss tell me that they never approached for such concerns.
On one hand they told me that your employer provided you with an affidavit of support letter which they recognised, but at same time they told that it was an owner tax returns and not yours.
I am going on pre action protocol please guide me on this

It would be helpful to see the refusal letter itself, please upload a copy with personal information redacted. You’ve tagged your question serial refusals, is that correct? How many previous refusals? What was the outcome of eg any legal advice you’ve sought on your refusal?

No it is my first refusal
